# Echo Cancellation with Pure Data

Tags: echo

I'm working on a project that requires the use of the microphone and I'm getting an annoying echo. Now all the examples I find of acousticEchoCanceler use a variable called microphoneId, something like:

`AcousticEchoCanceler acousticEchoCanceler=AcousticEchoCanceler.create(microphoneId);
acousticEchoCanceler.setEnabled(true);`

but none of them show where that variable comes from. Any ideas?

BTW: The project works with a pure data patch.

Comment: I've tried deviceInfo[0].getId() and I've tried all the numbers form 0 to 50, and I always get: `2020-02-29 14:05:59.322 13816-13816/com.example.beltingphone E/AudioEffect: set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -22
2020-02-29 14:05:59.322 13816-13816/com.example.beltingphone E/AudioEffects-JNI: AudioEffect initCheck failed -3
2020-02-29 14:05:59.322 13816-13816/com.example.beltingphone E/AudioEffect-JAVA: Error code -3 when initializing AudioEffect.
2020-02-29 14:05:59.323 13816-13816/com.example.beltingphone W/AcousticEchoCanceler: not enough memory`

Comment: I forgot to say I've also tried all the numbers from 0 to 1o in the deviceInfo array.

Comment: I discovered that the object does get created, but the trouble begins when I enable it; even if I set it to false.

Comment: Following someone's adivice, I also tried using STREAM_VOICE_CALL instead of echocanceler, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Still trying to brute-force this, I created a loop 
`while (acousticEchoCanceler==null) {
           acousticEchoCanceler = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(i);
           i++;
            Log.i("msg", ""+i);
       }`
It got to 548 and gave me an "EOF" error.

Comment: I discovered I had to use audiorecord, but the mistake I get is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this to capture the current active audiorecord with the mic

```
am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);    
activeAudioRecord = am.getActiveRecordingConfigurations();
int audioSessionID = activeAudioRecord.get(0).getClientAudioSessionId();
```